After npx expo prebuild, npx expo run:android wont work
I just installed a fresh react native app using
npx create-expo-app --template tabs
Then I proceeded with the following command
npx expo prebuild
Which ran and completed successfully. So I'm trying to run my app on my android emulator using the command npx expo run:android but I get an error I don't understand as shown on the image below.
The error I get when try to run my app
package.json
{
  "name": "fin",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "~50.0.17",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.3",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.10",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.9.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.8.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~50.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "fin",
    "slug": "fin",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "fin",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.jbac76.fin"
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static",
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router"
    ],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
    }
  }
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".expo/types/**/*.ts",
    "expo-env.d.ts"
  ]
}

I hope the information I have provided is enough. I have googled this issue for hours with no success, This is my last hope so I appreciate in advance.
Tried to reinstall my android studio and emulator.
Tried to reinstall node js.
Tried to reinstall jdk.
Tried to re-create the project.
Tried to clear cache.
All in all I'm relatively new to this so i wasn't sure what to try other than googling for solutions.
By the way, I was following a youtube tutorial by Simon building a Fintech clone with react-native.

Hi there! Please read how to ask for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow. Also, please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. If you're not aware, you didn't post a link to the tutorial use are using. You also did not post any code that is a minimal working example. The error says that punycode can no longer be used. I don't know if you added that, but you need to find an alternative module.
